# Prediction using cross correlation model

Tags: r, lag, predict, cross-correlation

I'm pretty new in R and I'm working on a cross correlation model, I've searched for the answer but haven't been able to find it.

I have been able to prove the cross correlation(lag correlation) between 2 time series using the R function with "ccf".

Now based on the model created with ccf I want to be able to predict the next values of one of the variables based on the data of the other one. I don't seem to find information.

This is relatively easy in auto-correlation with Arima, but I don't seem to be able to do it with the cross correlation.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks
Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the help, the purpose of the ccf function is:

```
Function ccf computes the cross-correlation or cross-covariance of two univariate series
```

This means it's not a model as you state in your question, it's a computation. 
What you should do is use the `ccf` function for plotting and choosing a model for prediction such as ARIMA, VAR, etc. [Check out the time series task in CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) for more options regarding time series modelling.

Perhaps your question should be posted in stats.exchange rather than stackoverflow, as it's not a programming question.

This would be an example of the usage of ccf() in case this is useful for you.

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), length = 100, by = "month"),
                 x = (runif(n = 100, min = 0, max = 1000)),
                 y = rpois(n = 100, lambda = 50))

cc = with(df, ccf(x, y, type = "correlation"))

plot(cc)
```

Comment: Martin, that's of great help. Now I understand why ccf alone is not enought. I'll checkstats.exchange. THANKS